# overriding body background color in angular 7

Tags: css, angular

I have been trying to override the background body of my login and register components but it's not working 
I tried adding a div with a CSS class setting its background color but the bottom part of the page isn't set to the color I picked.
I would appreciate any suggestion on the best way to solve it.

```
  .login-page{
    height: 100% !important;
    background-color: #e40134 !important;
   }
```

Comment: What do you see when inspecting the component in browser's console? What overwrites the above background-color?

Answer (score 2):

If you want change the class of body in some components you use ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy

```
  //inject in the constructor the "document"
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document) { }

  //in init you add a class to de body
  ngOnInit() {
    this._document.body.classList.add('new-body-class');
  }
  //in destroy remove the class
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._document.body.classList.remove('new-body-class');
  }
```

And

```
.new-body-class{
   background-color: #e40134;
}
```

The `new-body-class` can be a class defined in `styles.css` or you can use `ViewEncapsulation.None`. Be Carefull, `ViewEncapsulation.None` makes that the .css of the componet is common to all the aplication, so if you write, e.g.

```
h5{color:red}
.new-body-class{
   background-color: #e40134;
}
```

futhermore change the background, **all** yours h5 in your application becomes red

Answer (score 1):

Use **encapsulation** key at **@Component**

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'login-page',
  templateUrl: './login-page.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

and use <kbd>::ng-deep</kbd> in css => https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

for example:

```
::ng-deep .login-page {
    height: 100% !important;
    background-color: #e40134 !important;
}
```

These are the different ways of encapsulation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
  .login-page{
    height: 100vh !important;
    background-color: #e40134 !important;
   }
```

If with this you still do not have the expected result you can add `position: absolute`. 
In any case you can always reset the body by applying a `margin: 0`. It would be very helpful to know what you see if you inspect it with the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually a problem because your  has a margin by default.

So in `styles.scss`, I would just add this:

```
body: {
  margin: 0
}
```