# Angular apply body stylesheet conditionally

Tags: angular, angular2viewencapsulation

I would like to change body background color when a specific component (in my case, login component) is visible The login component is loaded using router-outlet from app component.

I tried adding body background color stylesheet in the login component's css and set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`, it works but it also changed entire application's background color.

Is there any way to only set body stylesheet when loading a specific component (in my case, login component)?

Comment: If the login component spreads to the whole page, why not just change that components background color?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55784432/overriding-body-background-color-in-angular-7/65733221#65733221

Comment: @eko, yeah that might be an option.

Comment: @Eliseo, it looks good, I will give a try, thanks.