# How can I change a body tag class when url route

Tags: angular

**my index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">


</head>
<body class="header">
  <div class="preload preload-container">
    <div class="preload-logo"></div>
    </div>
  <app-root></app-root>


  <a id="scroll-top"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

**here only home page target body class `<body class="header">` and other routes urls target `<body class="header main">`**

**here only home page target body class  and other routes urls target**

Comment: Does it really need to be the body?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55784432/overriding-body-background-color-in-angular-7/65733221#65733221

Answer (score 0):

you can use ngif.

```html
<body class="header" *ngif="something()">
  <div class="preload preload-container">
    <div class="preload-logo"></div>
    </div>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <a id="scroll-top"></a>

</body>

<body class="header main" *ngif="something()>
  <other-root></other-root>
</body>
```